# Profiling scipy.weave inline codes

Tags: python, profiling, scipy

I use `scipy.weave` for performance critical parts in python scripts. If possible, I parallelize these codes using OpenMP. I experience bottlenecks in some cases, which is probably due to false sharing. How do I profile these inline codes, i.e. any suggestions for suitable tools on Linux platforms ?

See a bad vector addition implementation below, which is prone to false sharing.

```
from scipy.weave import inline
import numpy as np
import time

N = 1000
a = np.random.rand(N)
b = np.random.rand(N)
c = np.random.rand(N)

cpus = 4
weave_options = {'headers'           : ['<omp.h>'],
                 'extra_compile_args': ['-fopenmp -O3'],
                 'extra_link_args'   : ['-lgomp'],
                 'compiler'          : 'gcc'}

code = \
r"""
omp_set_num_threads(cpus);
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
      for ( int i=0; i<N; i++ ){
         c[i] = a[i]+b[i];
      }
}
"""

now = time.time()
inline(code,['a','b','c','N','cpus'],**weave_options)
print "TOOK {0:.4f}".format(time.time()-now)
print "SUCCESS" if np.all(np.equal(a,a)) else "FAIL"
```

EDIT:

It is possible to use

`valgrind --tool=callgrind --simulate-cache=yes python ***.py`

and `kcachegrind ./callgrind.out.****` to at least get a slight
impression. But the result tend to become messy for these kinds
of wrapping codes.